# what the most efficient way to by call API?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, rest, webapi

I am using .net core console Application using C#.

I have one API (say API 1) which give me DataID. passing this DataID I need to call another API (say API 2) which will give me list of vehiclesId. like calling Get ../api/{DataID}/vehicles/ gives below

```
                   {
                    "vehicleIds": [
                                    603285889,
                                    1328361472,
                                    1333092761,
                                    1595876995,
                                    799206723
                                  ]
                   }
```

By Passing DataID and VehicleID to another API (say API 3) I will get Vehicle details along with DealerId. Like calling Get ../api/{DataId}/vehicles/{VehicleId} gives below

```
   {
        "vehicleId": 2063928446,
        "year": 2004,
        "make": "MINI",
        "model": "Cooper",
        "dealerId": 1508315732
    }
```

Now passing DataId and DealerId to another API (say API 4) I will get Dealer Name . Like calling Get ../api/{DataId}/dealers/{DealerId} gives below

> {
> "dealerId": 1508315732,
> "name": "Bob's Cars"
> }

what the most efficient way to  call API?

Looping through list is possible and calling API for each item But I am looking for better and efficient way.
I am using .net core console Application using C# and using HttpClient.

Comment: do you have control over the API design where you can pass multiple dealers for example or multiple vehicles?

Comment: _I am looking for better and efficient way_ - please provide concreate description of what is better and efficient, for example why calling it in the loop is not efficient?

Comment: I target to get result under 20 seconds but i am able to get over 30 seconds

Answer (score 0):

This is a dependency problem, where you have to wait before you proceed to the next call.

Make the first call multiple times, this way you have a batch of DataIDs, or even get a list of DataIDs, and then you can spawn off multiple calls using a threading mechanism.